# BSRR seems to work backwards

Tags: led, stm32

I'm testing my BluePill and I'm trying to turn on the built-in LED.

Everything seems fine but one thing. When writing to BSRR I would expect the LED to turn on.

When I write 1 to BS13 bit `GPIOC->BSRR = (0x2000)` and turn off when I write `GPIOC->BSRR = (0x2000) << 16u` (writing 1 to BSR13 bit). To my surprise, it works backwards - LED turns on when `GPIOC->BSRR = (0x2000) << 16u` and turns off when  `GPIOC->BSRR = (0x2000)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a schematic showing how the internal LED is connected? A microcontroller can either sink current (provide the negative connection to the cathode) or source current (provide the positive connection to the anode).

Comment: Look at the schematic ... is the LED connected (ia a resistor) to GND, or +V?

Comment: You're right, I just checked - the LED is connected to VCC, so the pin has to a GND so the current can flow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blue Pill connects the LED between VCC and a GPIO (rather than between a GPIO and ground), so logic 0 turns it on and logic 1 turns it off.

Comment: Although less true today than it was, historically speaking due to the difference in electron vs "hole" mobility digital outputs could "sink" much more negative current than they could "source" positive current, so it became traditional to drive the *low* side of loads rather than the high side.  You see the same thing with power FET's driving relays, motors, etc typically being placed as low side switches.